# Keep Getting memory full Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, memory

I have reset my laptop to factory settings a couple of times since 2013
trying to make computer faster.

This last time I did because memory keeps saying full and shutting me down.

I have taken all pictures and docs off. Now when online or not it shuts me down due to memory. I have deleted Avira. and shut down running apps with task manager.

I am not tech savvy. I have been searching for days, and to fix this. I found this site today.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: To begin with, please post screen snapshots of: 1) Task Manager's Performance tab, "Memory" section and 2) Task Manager's Details tab, sorted by the "Commit size" column (which you'll have to add, it's not there by default). n.b. The "memory" column in TM's "Processes" tab is useless for this problem, as are the "working set" columns in TM's "Details" tab.

Comment: Also include a screenshot of your Virtual Memory settings in windows.